# como quitar espacios en blancos de mi base de datos ya que uso el tipo de datos chart

Tags: sql

Tengo una tabla para nombre del producto y una tabla para el nombre del cliente, y los campos de nombre del prpoducto y nombre del cliente los extraigo y los pongo en un combobox, pero al momento de hacer eso me los trae con espacios en blanco si el nombre es de 14 caracteres y el tamano de mi campo es de 25 me trae los 25 espacios y solo quiero que me traiga los caracteres esto es usando sql y visual estudio 2015

Answer (score 1):

El tipo de dato `char` es de una longitud fija, por lo que siempre agregará espacios al final de la cadena. Para evitar esto, puedes usar el tipo de dato `varchar` que tiene longitud variable y elimina los espacios a la derecha.

Answer (score 0):

Si necesitas eliminar los espacios en blanco puedes utilizar LTRIM() y RTRIM según sea necesario o incluso los dos, por ejemplo:

`SELECT LTRIM(NOMBRE) FROM USUARIOS` Ó `SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(NOMBRE)) FROM USUARIO`

también puedes concatenar datos para que salgan en una sola celda, por ejemplo:

```
,LTRIM(RTRIM(NOMBRE)) + ' '+ LTRIM(RTRIM(APELLIDO)) AS NOMBRECOMPLETO
```